# Restkit 0.20 instantiate NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

In the old Restkit 0.10, in my code I have my temp entities being instantiated like so:

Message *newMessage = [Message object];

The Restkit update guide has gotten me pretty far.  Most of my stuff is working.  Im down to this last detail.

What is the equivalent of this with the new RestKit?

I think the object keyword is some type of RestKit method that initializes the object for core data, but not sure what its doing and it doesn't work now with the new RestKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact same feature doesn't exist. The closest is [`insertNewObjectForEntityForName:`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Categories/NSManagedObjectContext+RKAdditions.html#//api/name/insertNewObjectForEntityForName%3a) but this is a context method, not a managed object method.

If you class names always match your entity names then it is easy to implement the old method yourself. Or you could grab the old code (it's a category so easy to add to your project explicitly).